# How to remove event callback with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I have a web application that page A has video, and page B doesn't. The video has the `onended` event when it finishes video playback. I tried to remove the event before the component unmounts with `removeEventListener`, or the video ended event will be fired after I switched to page B.

However, I cannot find the proper way to remove callback with parameters.
I used the arrow function and bind to pass parameters, but these two methods made event removal impossible.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  // 1st trial: anonymous function cannot be removed
  this.video.onended = () => this.videoOnEndedCallback(params);
  // 2nd trial: bind() creates new function, cannot be referenced either
  this.video.onended = this.videoOnEndedCallback.bind(this, params);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.video.removeEventListener('ended', this.videoOnEndedCallback);
}
```

Lastly, I set the `onended` to `null`, and it works.

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.video.onended = null;
}
```

**Question**

If setting `onended` to `null` equals the effect of `removeEventListener`?

If not, is there any other proper way to remove callback with parameters?

Comment: `removeEventListener` removes listeners added with `addEventListener` not assigned directly as a handler i.e. `element.onclick = () => alert('hi');`. Assigning `null` is the correct way to remove a directly assigned handler. When using event listeners to remove a listener you must pass `removeEventListener` a reference to the exact function added previously by `addEventListener`.

Comment: @JacobSmit Do you mean `this.video.removeEventListener('ended', callback)` only works for `this.video.addEventListener('ended', callback)`?

Comment: Yep. `addEventLister` / `removeEventListener` are for [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) and `element.onclick` or similar is an [Event Handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

Comment: Also yes to the function must be the same reference so `const eventListener = () => alert('test'); element.addEventListener('click', eventListener); element.removeEventListener('click', eventListener);` will function as expected, but `element.addEventListener('click', () => alert('test')); element.removeEventListener('click', () => alert('test'));` would not.

Comment: It seems I need to have an extra variable to keep a reference to the arrow function. 
`this.arrowCallback = () => this.callback(params)` 
Then, I can have a reference `this.arrowCallback` for `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the event listener was set using the named event property (`.onended` in this case), it can be changed by reassigning and removed by setting it to `null`. (Only a single listener per event can be set up this way.)

The other way, `.addEventListener()`, can register multiple event listeners for the same event, cannot be changed and can only be removed by `.removeEventListener()` (requires a reference to the set listener).

These two ways work along with each other, but either way, you have to choose the method for each listener to be used for adding/changing/removing that listener.

In your case, it's easier to use the event listener property, as if you `.bind()` the function, you won't have the reference to the new function, so you won't be able to remove it by `.removeEventListener()`.

On the other hand, if you store its reference, you can also use the `.addEventListener()`/`.removeEventListener()` methods:

```
constructor(){
  this.boundVideoOnEndedCallback = this.videoOnEndedCallback.bind(this, params); //You can also use the arrow-function-version here
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.video.addEventListener('ended', this.boundVideoOnEndedCallback)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.video.removeEventListener('ended', this.boundVideoOnEndedCallback);
}
```